# Mathematica appending a Matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, append

I have to solve a system of non-linear equations for a wide range of parameter space. I'm using FindRoot, which is sensitive to initial start point so I have to do it by hand and by trial and error and plotting, rather than putting the equations in a loop or in a table.

So what I want to do is create a database or a Matrix with a fixed number of columns but variable number of rows so I can keep appending it with new results as and when I solve for them.

Right now I've used something like:

```
{{{xx, yy}} = {x, y} /. FindRoot[{f1(x,y) == 0,f2(x,y)==0}, {x,a},{y,b}],
g(xx,yy)} >>> "Attempt1.txt"
```

Where I am solving for two variables and then storing the variables and also a function g(xx,yy) of the variables.

This seems to work for me but the result is not a Matrix any more but the data is stored as some text type thing.

Is there anyway I can get this to stay a matrix or a database where I keep adding rows to it each time I solve for FindRoot by hand? Again, I need to do FindRoot by hand because it is sensitive to the start points and I don't know the good start points without first plotting it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand why this is not a matrix anymore. Consider this `Put[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, "tmp.mx"]; Get["tmp.mx"]` which is exactly the same expression after it is imported again.

Comment: It's storing everything as one entry. Suppose I did data=Import["temp.mx"] and then  I do dimensions[data], it answers 1. I have no idea how to extract the information. When I do data[[1]] it outputs the entire data. I cannot extract individual pieces of information. When I do data[[1,1]] is gives an error.

Comment: So I had done     {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x8,x10} >>> "temp.mx" 22 times inside the For loop. Now when I did    data=Import["temp.mx","Table"] and then do Dimensions[data] I get 110. What I really wanted was a matrix with 10 columns and 22 rows. Each of my 10 data per row/record is stored as 5 pieces of data, giving a total dimension of 5x22=110. For example, data[[1]]={"{24258.225756005108,", "0.0001254874133927587,", \
"0.10668678000535163,"} and so on. Is there anyway I can get my data in a clean 10x22 matrix where data[[i,j]] represents the jth value for the ith record? Thanks.

Comment: Oh I neglected to point out that the data was generated in a loop.(I've done this first outside a loop when I had to hand pick the starting points etc. then later I did some calculations in a loop. So I guess my follow up question is for the second loop case)

    For[i=1,i<23,i++,{f1(i),f2(i),..,f10(i)}>>>"temp.mx"]

Now when I try to Import "temp.mx" I get all kinds of things except a 22x10 matrix that I really badly want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, this should work

```
results = {};
results = Append[Flatten[{{xx, yy} = {x, y} /. FindRoot[{f1(x,y) == 0,f2(x,y)==0}, {x,a},{y,b}],g(xx,yy)}],results];
```

Then every time you're tying to add a line to the matrix results by hand, you would just type

```
results = Append[Flatten[{{xx, yy} = {x, y} /. FindRoot[{f1(x,y) == 0,f2(x,y)==0}, {x,a},{y,b}],g(xx,yy)}],results];
```

By the way, to get around the problem of sensitivity to the initial a and b values, you could explore the parameter space in a loop, varying the parameters slowly and using the solution of x and y from the previous loop iteration for your new a and b values each time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved by using `Read` instead of `Get`. While `Get` reads the complete file in one run, `Read` can be adjusted to extract a single `Expression`, `Byte`, `Number` and many more. So what you should do is open your file and read expression after expression and pack it inside a list.

```
PutAppend[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, "tmp.mx"]
PutAppend[{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, "tmp.mx"]
PutAppend[{{9, 23}, {11, 12}}, "tmp.mx"]
PutAppend[{{13, 14}, {15, 16}}, "tmp.mx"]

stream = OpenRead["tmp.mx"];
mat = ArrayPad[
   NestWhileList[Read[stream, Expression] &, 
    stream = OpenRead["tmp.mx"], # =!= EndOfFile &], -1];
Close[stream];
```

And now you have in `mat` a list containing all lines. The `ArrayPad`, which cuts off one element at each end is necessary because the first element contains the output of the `OpenRead` and the last element contains `EndOfFile`. If you are not familiar with functional constructs like `NestWhileList` then you can put it in a loop as you like, since it is really just the iterated calls to `Read`

```
stream = OpenRead["tmp.mx"];
mat = {};
AppendTo[mat, Read[stream, Expression]];
AppendTo[mat, Read[stream, Expression]];
AppendTo[mat, Read[stream, Expression]];
AppendTo[mat, Read[stream, Expression]];
Close[stream];
```